# Java- Can we compress a local database and connect the archive with EmbeddedDriver

Tags: java, jar, zip, compression, javadb

I want to Compresses my Entire database folder(jar or zip) and connect it with EmbeddedDriver.

1. Can I do that?
2. Is there anyway to reduce the size of a database and keep it at a working condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your JavaDB/Derby database into a compressed ZIP file. See the Derby Developer Guide: [Transferring read-only databases to archive (jar or zip) files](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/tdevdeploy33704.html).

But this is only possible for read-only databases.